# Can a variable be used for the url in a .load event

Tags: jquery, variables, onload

I want to change a URL to a variable so I can apply to an menu. The Code below works fine but I can't work out how to add the variable.. I want to change "/inks/mimaki/jv33-cjv"

Working Code >>

```
jQuery('#catList-dump li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = jQuery(this).attr('href')
});

jQuery("#main-nav-services").append("<ul>");

jQuery("#main-nav-services ul").load("/inks/mimaki/jv33-cjv #catListholder .catalogueList");
```

Trying to use the variable  >>

```
jQuery('#catList-dump li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loadpage = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery("#main-nav-services ul").load('"+loadpage+" #catListholder .catalogueList'); 

});
```

If someone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The variable should not be in quotes nor the `+` sign;
`jQuery("#main-nav-services ul").load('loadpage + #catListholder.catalogueList');`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes, anything inside quotes is treated as a string

```
jQuery('#catList-dump li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var loadpage = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    jQuery("#main-nav-services ul").load( loadpage + " #catListholder .catalogueList"); 
});
```